# SQL query get newest item if two dates are the same in group by day

Tags: sql

I'm working on a reporting system where there should only be the newest entry of each day over multiple days returned by my SQL query so that there's no dupes in the report. MY current query works fine in that if there are more than one entry on any given day it will get the newest entry for that day in my `INNER JOIN`, the problem that I'm facing though is if two `created` values for a report are exactly the same it returns both entries, I only need one.

Here's my query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tlp_consolidated_reports AS ConsolidatedReport
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DATE(created) AS created_at,
        MAX(created) AS max_created_at
    FROM
        tlp_consolidated_reports
    WHERE
        type = 'commissions'
        AND
        user_id = '33'
        AND
        report_from >= '2022-08-01 00:00:00'
        AND
        report_to <= '2022-08-31 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
) AS joinedReport
  ON joinedReport.created_at = DATE(ConsolidatedReport.created)
  AND
  joinedReport.max_created_at = ConsolidatedReport.created
WHERE
    ConsolidatedReport.type = 'commissions'
    AND
    ConsolidatedReport.user_id = '33'
    AND
    ConsolidatedReport.report_from >= '2022-08-01 00:00:00'
    AND
    ConsolidatedReport.report_to <= '2022-08-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY
    ConsolidatedReport.created DESC
```

I tried added a `LIMIT 1` into my `INNER JOIN` just after the `GROUP BY` but then this only ever returns one entry over the whole period which isn't right.

Example:

Reports:

```
2022-08-09 21:00:00
2022-08-08 15:00:00
2022-08-07 14:00:00
2022-08-07 14:00:00
2022-08-07 13:00:00
```

Currently returns

```
2022-08-09 21:00:00
2022-08-07 14:00:00
2022-08-07 14:00:00
```

So the 7th is returning the newest, but because the `created` is the same, it returns both, how can I limit it to **one** if this scenario is encountered?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: You omit some cruicial information - you need a tie-break but don't explain it.

Comment: @Stu okay, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the creation date is the same, then return any of them?

```sql
WITH data AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY created) AS numb
FROM tlp_consolidated_reports
WHERE
        type = 'commissions'
        AND
        user_id = '33'
        AND
        report_from >= '2022-08-01 00:00:00'
        AND
        report_to <= '2022-08-31 23:59:59'
)
SELECT data.*
FROM data 
JOIN (
    SELECT max(numb) AS numb
    FROM data
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
) AS grData ON data.numb = grData.numb
ORDER BY data.created DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).